# Expense of using System.debug

Tags: performance, logging

I've seen code on an inherited project output debug info while iterating large collections of objects.

`System.debug(Logginglevel.DEBUG, 'sQuery=' + sQuery);`

If the system logging level is set higher than DEBUG in the above example, how expensive is something like this to keep in the code?

Are there any short-circuits that prevent the construction of two String objects above to construct the message that may be output?

Best practices on leaving junk like this in production codebases?

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least related: [Writing too much to debug log would affect APEX trigger or Visualforce page performance?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41063/writing-too-much-to-debug-log-would-affect-apex-trigger-or-visualforce-page-perf)

Comment: Related. My question was focused on debug logs that wouldn't be written. (Level is lower than current log level output setting)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have seen too many debugs double the processing time and at times cause the apex time limit exceeded. There is a cost to everything we do.

In addition writing

```
system.debug('Here');
```

is less costly than:

```
system.debug('Key: ' + k + ' - Map Value: ' + map.get(k));
```

The exact cost depends on how many debugs, are they in a loop, and exactly what / how they are debugging.

If you want to see, take any code with debugs, execute it with the console open, and check out the Execution Overview - Timeline.

Repeat with the debugs commented out.

Do that several times to average out system delays and you will see the primate cost of the debugs in your class

**As to your last question:**

Directly - **No**

Indirectly - you can have a global custom setting that you can check to enable debug statements. Then you can conditionally output the debugs. This would require you to update your code to check the custom setting value.

This will reduce the cost during runtime and still allow you to "flip a switch" to get the debug output. There is still a small cost for the constant evaluation of the flag though.

Comment: Someone should write a set of ant tasks to programmatically comment out all debug lines and just incorporate that into an Ant build file using the SF Deployment/Migration tool.

Comment: a hierarchical custom setting that allows one to enable logs for specific running users/profiles can be especially handy