# how to debug individual elements in list of wrapper class

Tags: apex

```
public static void getWrapper(List<WrapperClass> wra) {

    system.debug(wra);
    system.debug(wra.size());
    system.debug(wra[0]);//apex exception

    //apex exception
    for(WrapperClass w:wra) {
        system.debug(w);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by debug you mean see all the data, this generally works well:

```
system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(wra));
```

because it shows all the array elements and all the fields. (Note occasionally this call will fail when there are self-references in the structure.)

On the other hand this:

```
system.debug(String.valueOf(wra));
```

only shows a summary of the array and fields to avoid consuming an open-ended amount of CPU time and log file space.

**Do not** leave the former style of debugging in your final code; in one code-base, we were consuming 30% of the CPU time to simply generate the JSON strings for the debug logging (whether or not we were actually recording the debug logs.

Comment: I need individual element of list of wraapper class.

Comment: @maneesha The JSON will show the list and the individual items it contains. If you only want to see one item at a time, loop and output each item in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop within the Developer Console (or another SDK that supports it), rather than using system.debug(...) statements in your code, make use of checkpoints. There's a few reasons for this:

1. System.debug(...) statements aren't efficient and use CPU time
   ([Expense of using System.debug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93200/expense-of-using-system-debug))

   2. Debug logs age out and you might miss the logs and the opportunity to troubleshoot.
   3. Checkpoints are dynamic - you can place them during testing and you can place them during live execution during production runtime.
      You're not limited to where you've coded your system.debug commands.
   4. The information they provide is generally much greater - you don't just get the specific information you've placed within the
      system.debug statement, you get most variables stored within memory
      at the moment the checkpoint is hit.

Having said that, they're not great at providing information about the contents of arrays and are just typically a pointer in to memory and an indication of allocated size of the array.

Here's the Salesforce guide for checkpoints: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5